# How does CALayer geometryFlipped behave exactly?

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics, core-animation, cgaffinetransform

Let's assume i have a CGPathRef called somePath and I'm doing this:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shapeLayer.path = somePath;
shapeLayer.geometryFlipped = YES;
```

But for some reason i don't want to flip the geometry – i'd want to do something like this:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
CGAffineTransform flipTransform = ........;
shapeLayer.path = CGPathApplyAffineTransform(somePath, &flipTransform);
shapeLayer.geometryFlipped = NO;
```

How would the flipTransform have to look like to make the layer display exactly the same as before?

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGAffineTransform flipTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);`